# lwc table doesn't refresh if I toggle a template to show a different view

Tags: lightning-web-components

Working on a custom table. There are two types of the table defined in the HTML, view and edit. I click on an edit button to expose the edit table and hide the view table. I make changes to the table and click save. If I don't toggle back to the view table and hide the edit table, the table refreshes with the correct values. I want to go back to the view state though, so I toggle the template to show the view state of the table and hide the edit table which does not update the view state with the correct values. I've tried moving around editTable=false just about everywhere. Any ideas?

HTML

```
//view table
            <template if:false={editTable}>
                <template if:true={dataLoaded}>
                    <template for:each={taskResourceList} for:item="mr">
                        <div key={mr.Id} class="">
                            <lightning-record-view-form 
                                record-id={mr.Id}
                                object-api-name="Mission_Resource__c">

                                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-stretch slds-border_bottom slds-size_12-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_right">
                                        <div class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-right_small slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_xxx-small">
                                            <lightning-output-field 
                                                variant="label-hidden"
                                                field-name="Quantity_Filled__c">
                                            </lightning-output-field>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_right">
                                        <div class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-right_small slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_xxx-small">
                                            <lightning-output-field 
                                                variant="label-hidden" 
                                                field-name="Quantity__c">
                                            </lightning-output-field>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </lightning-record-view-form>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                    
                </template>
                <div class="slds-size_12-of-12 slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-top_x-small" 
                                        variant="brand" 
                                        type="edit" 
                                        label="Edit Resource" 
                                        onclick={handleEdit}>
                    </lightning-button>
                </div>
            </template>
//edit table
        <template if:true={editTable}>
            <template if:true={dataLoaded}>
                <template for:each={taskResourceList} for:item="mr">
                    <div key={mr.Id} class="">
                        <lightning-record-edit-form 
                            record-id={mr.Id}
                            object-api-name="Mission_Resource__c">

                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-stretch slds-border_bottom slds-size_12-of-12">
                                <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_right">
                                    <div class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-right_small slds-m-top_xxx-small slds-m-bottom_xxx-small">
                                        <lightning-input-field 
                                            variant="label-hidden"
                                            name="Quantity_Filled__c"
                                            onchange={handleChange} 
                                            data-id={mr.Id} 
                                            field-name="Quantity_Filled__c" 
                                            value={mr.Quantity_Filled__c}>
                                        </lightning-input-field>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_right">
                                    <div class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-right_small slds-m-top_xxx-small slds-m-bottom_xxx-small">
                                        <lightning-input-field 
                                            disabled
                                            variant="label-hidden" 
                                            field-name="Quantity__c"
                                            value={mr.Quantity__c}>
                                        </lightning-input-field>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </lightning-record-edit-form>
                    </div>
                </template>
                
            </template>
            <div class="slds-size_12-of-12 slds-align_absolute-center">
                <lightning-button class="slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-top_x-small" 
                                    variant="neutral" 
                                    type="cancel" 
                                    label="Cancel" 
                                    onclick={handleCancel}>
                </lightning-button>
                <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-top_x-small" 
                                    variant="brand" 
                                    type="submit" 
                                    label="Save" 
                                    onclick={handleSaveAll}>
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
        </template>
```

js

```
displayResources() {
    console.log('------------displayResources-----------');
    this.dataLoaded = false;
    this.taskResourceList = [];
    getTaskResources({taskId : this.recordId})
    .then(data => {
        data.forEach(r => {
            r.qAndAs = this.questionAnswersMap[r?.Id];
            this.taskResourceList.push(r);
        });
        this.dataLoaded = true;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('----displayResources--ERROR-- ', error);
    });
}


handleSaveAll(event) {   //<--------first action
    console.log('----------handleSaveAll-----------');

    //this.mrListForUpdate.forEach(function(item, index) {
    this.dataLoaded = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.mrListForUpdate.length; i++) {
        
        let sfId = this.mrListForUpdate[i].Id;
        const tr = this.taskResourceList.find(obj => obj.Id === sfId);

        let oldQF = tr.Quantity_Filled__c ? Number(tr.Quantity_Filled__c) : 0;
        let newQF = Number(this.mrListForUpdate[i].Quantity_Filled__c);

        let tempQuantity = Number(tr.Quantity__c);
        console.log('tempQuantity -111- ', tempQuantity);
        if (oldQF != newQF) {
            if (oldQF > newQF) {
                tempQuantity += Number(oldQF - newQF);
            } else {
                tempQuantity += Number(oldQF - newQF);
            }
        }
        this.mrListForUpdate[i].Quantity__c = tempQuantity;
    }
    this.updateResources();    //<<<<<----------------------
}

updateResources() { //<--------second action
    console.log('----------updateResources-----------');
    saveMissionResourceChanges({ mrList: this.mrListForUpdate })
    .then((data) => {
        this.editTable = false;    //<-----------------------HERE--------if this line is removed it works-----------
        console.log('editTable --- is false');
        this.displayResources();     //<<<<<----------------------
        const toast = new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: 'Updated',
                                message: 'Resource Updated Successfully!',
                                variant: 'success',
                                mode: 'dismissable'
                                });
        this.dispatchEvent(toast);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('saveMissionResourceChanges - error --- ', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using taskResourceList for view table as well. Did not see the view table in the question. Can you please add it to check ?

Comment: @Rohit - I just added the view table to the original post. Yes I'm using taskResourceList for the view table as well

Comment: Sorry , out sick. will look into this tomorrow.

Comment: This might be happening due to consecutive changes in dom. Can you try by adding a delay to displayResources() in saveMissionResourceChanges callback like below : setTimeout(() => { this.displayResources() },300);

Comment: Thanks. Hope you feel better. Unfortunately, I added 18 seconds with the same results:
            `setTimeout(() => { this.displayResources() },18000);`

Comment: ohh , I'll try to replicate this tonight. This is an Interesting issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to add a comment but need to elaborate on the code. Hence , answering this question.

I tried below scenario and it worked. When we update the records using `lightning-record-edit-form`, after we fetch data , it gets updated instantly :

Markup :

```
<template>
  <lightning-button variant="base" label="Base" title="Looks like a link" onclick={handleEdit} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
  <template if:false={editTable}>
    <template for:each={contactList} for:item="mr">
      <div key={mr.Id} class="">
        <lightning-record-view-form
                                  record-id={mr.Id}
                                  object-api-name="Contact">
          <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-stretch slds-border_bottom slds-size_12-of-12">
            <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_right">
              <div class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-right_small slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_xxx-small">
                <lightning-output-field
                    variant="label-hidden"
                    field-name="Name">
                </lightning-output-field>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_right">
              <div class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-right_small slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_xxx-small">
                <lightning-output-field
                    variant="label-hidden"
                    field-name="Budget__c">
                </lightning-output-field>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_right">
              <div class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-right_small slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_xxx-small">
                  <lightning-output-field
                      variant="label-hidden"
                      field-name="Deals_Accepted__c">
                  </lightning-output-field>
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </lightning-record-view-form>
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>
  <template if:true={editTable}>
    <template for:each={contactList} for:item="mr" for:index="index">
      <div key={mr.Id} class="">
        <lightning-record-edit-form
                            record-id={mr.Id}
                            object-api-name="Contact">
          <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-stretch slds-border_bottom slds-size_12-of-12">
            <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_right">
              <div class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-right_small slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_xxx-small">
                <lightning-input-field
                  variant="label-hidden"
                  name="Budget__c"
                  onchange={handleChange}
                  data-id={index}
                  field-name="Budget__c"
                  value={mr.Budget__c}>
                </lightning-input-field>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_right">
              <div class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-right_small slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_xxx-small">
                <lightning-input-field
                  variant="label-hidden"
                  name="Deals_Accepted__c"
                  onchange={handleChange}
                  data-id={index}
                  field-name="Deals_Accepted__c"
                  value={mr.Deals_Accepted__c}>
              </lightning-input-field>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>
  <div class="slds-size_12-of-12 slds-align_absolute-center">
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-top_x-small"
                        variant="neutral"
                        type="cancel"
                        label="Cancel"
                        onclick={handleCancel}>
    </lightning-button>
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-top_x-small"
                        variant="brand"
                        type="submit"
                        label="Save"
                        onclick={handleSaveAll}>
    </lightning-button>
</div>
</template>
```

JS code :

```
 import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import saveContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.saveContacts';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContactList';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';


export default class FormsDemo extends LightningElement {
  editTable = false;
  @track contactList = [];
  contactListToApex = [];

  connectedCallback() {
    this.fetchAllContacts();
  }

  handleEdit() {
    this.editTable = true;
  }

  fetchAllContacts() {
    this.contactList = [];
    getContacts()
    .then(data => {
      console.log("testing ",data);
      data.forEach(obj => {
        this.contactList.push(Object.assign({}, obj));
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("error ",error);
    })
  }

  handleChange(event) {
  let newList = [];
    this.contactList.forEach(obj => {
      console.log("in loop");
      newList.push(Object.assign({}, obj));
    });
    let contactRec = newList[event.target.dataset.id];
    contactRec[event.target.name] = event.detail.value;
    console.log("event : ",newList);
    this.contactListToApex = newList;
  }

  handleSaveAll() {
    console.log("in Handle save");
    saveContacts({ contactList : this.contactListToApex})
    .then(data => {
      this.editTable = false;
      this.contactList.forEach(rec => {
        this.updateRecordView(rec.Id); // <---- Call method for each contact record or only the updated ones.
      });
      const toast = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Updated',
        message: 'Resource Updated Successfully!',
        variant: 'success',
        mode: 'dismissable'
        });
this.dispatchEvent(toast);

    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("error ",error);
    })
  }

  handleCancel() {

  }

  updateRecordView(recordId) {
    updateRecord({fields: { Id: recordId }}); <-- Method to refresh view data
}

}
```

Edit : Got this working.
Here, lightning-record-view data cannot be updated by just setting the references.
We need to use `updateRecord` method from `lightning/uiRecordApi` as shown above.
Related article - https://salesforceprofs.com/refresh-record-view-in-lwc/

Comment: data comes back fine... I can see it in the controller and in console. I can't get your example to work. 

Too many DML statements: 1

    `@AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean saveContacts(List<Contact> contactList) {
        try {
            System.debug('contactList-------'+contactList);
            update contactList;
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('ERROR------------'+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        
    }`

Comment: Do you have a trigger or Flow on contact in your org which is causing recursive updates? 
My example works fine when added on any record detail page for any object.

Comment: hmmm. I don't have anything special/extra going on

Comment: got your's to work. I added the name output to the edtiTable= true section. IDK why but it saved and refreshed. I'll dig in and let you know if I find anything that helps me

Comment: Sure , maybe you can try reducing your code to a basic version like mine and then start adding changes to check.

Comment: Hi @Rohit - after switching your code around I found that it behaves the same way as mine. Starting in a view mode (add edit button and function) click edit to make edit visible, make changes and save. The view section doesn't get updated until page refresh. Any ideas? I can attach code if needed, but it's just switching and starting in a view state

Comment: Hi @mackmama, I will check this in a while. But got your point. I will try it shortly.

Comment: @mackmama : Got this working. Updated the answer with the solution.

Comment: that worked!! Thank you for seeing this one through.

Comment: Thank you. It was an interesting issue and learnt through it. Had used lighting-record-view long time back.This refreshed my memory.